# Why Query performance improve by calling UDF using subquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, user-defined-functions

I recently realized that by calling UDF in a subquery perform much better that calling them directly, why this happen?

As an example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [CurrentYearStart]()
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Date DATETIME;
    SELECT top 1 @Date = StartPeriod
    FROM SystemPeriods WITH (NOLOCK);
    RETURN @Date;
END
```

ProviderServiceAreas have 412585 rows.

The following Query returns in about 50s

```
SELECT   PayGroup, SystemType, MAX(EffDt) AS MaxEffDt
FROM     CAT.ProviderServiceAreas
WHERE    EffDt > CurrentYearStart() 
GROUP BY Paygroup, SystemType
```

Execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJCom7vgm

The following Query returns in about 1s

```
SELECT   PayGroup, SystemType, MAX(EffDt) AS MaxEffDt
FROM     CAT.ProviderServiceAreas
WHERE    EffDt > (SELECT CurrentYearStart()) 
GROUP BY Paygroup, SystemType
```

Execution plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HkolVQDx7

Comment: Maybe query caching similar to https://blog.jooq.org/2011/09/02/oracle-scalar-subquery-caching/

Comment: what are the execution plans for both?

Comment: Wild guess, as @lad2025 alludes, the subquery w/function only runs once, but the function runs for each row.

Comment: I analized the execution plans and I noticed that by calling the function in the subquery they only execute the function once, in the other case they do per each record, this obviously performs better, but the question is why? why this happen?

Comment: `I noticed that by calling the function in the subquery they only execute the function once` => Caching :)

Anyway your function is very dangerous (TOP 1 without ORDER  BY + NOLOCK)

Comment: ok, but why they can't cache the function result?

Comment: @IsraelGarcia Because this function is not deterministic. `SELECT OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('[dbo].[StartPeriod]'), 'IsDeterministic')`

Comment: @lad2025 not necessarily, since presumably op executed both queries again and got the same behavior

Comment: The function is not deterministic fine, (select <function name>) is not deterministic as well.

Comment: I guess it behaves as in Oracle (it is inteded please read article: `in scalar subqueries, function results may be cached! While this can be very useful for performance, it can also be very dangerous for consistency – as with any caching mechanism, but this one is highly implicit! `)

Comment: I would get rid of that function regardless. Scalar functions are notoriously poor performers. Either convert it to an inline table valued function or just do a subquery.

Comment: To me, both queries should behave like they are behaving. I would interpret the second one as logically the same as using a variable and setting its value to the result of the function: `SELECT @Variable = StartPeriod()` and then using that variable: `WHERE EffDt > @Variable`. In the first query you are actually saying that you want every row to be greater than the result of the function as evaluated right now

Comment: Well this is true, but the query were used in a view, so I had to find a workaround.

Comment: The Sub-query only needs to populate once, as has been said previously. This is a natural process for SQL. Any function within a SELECT query will need to populate for each and every single row that relates to the SELECT query, that is again, a normal SQL process. Perhaps you're getting stuck on the fact that you think the two are the same process, but they are definitely not.

Comment: Well, I understand are not the same process, just trying to understand what is behind this, seems like the answer is that the subquery are cached and function call are not.

Comment: @lad2025 even if I declare the function WITH SCHEMABINDING and "isdeterministic" returns true, there is no changes in the behavior.

Comment: Its not really caching. that would imply that the function is being excuted more than once and replaying a cached result. I'd imagine more a different  tree shape that evaluates the function once and then uses the result as a correlated paramter.

Comment: @MartinSmith seems like this is what is happening... as per execution plan shows, in the subquery scenario the function is called one time and the WHERE is evaluated against the result of the subquery as a parameter.

Comment: The behaviour does make sense to me. If you imagine the SELECT without a from as being a SELECT against a virtual single row table then it is still being executed once per row against that virtual table. (But from the fact that Gordon's answer apparently doesn't do the trick this rationalisation doesn't look reliable - generally the QO doesn't make many guarantees about this kind of thing so I'm not sure how reliable the technique in this Q will be either)

Comment: I attached executions plan

Comment: i agree with Sean Lange about getting rid of the scalar udf - with these, performance problems are generally the rule rather than the exception. Try turning it into an inline table valued udf - performance should be much better.  Also, IIRC, execution plans, when scalar udfs   are involved - can be deceiving - i've seen execution plans that looked quick, but wasn't reflected in actual performance.

Comment: @MoeSisko that was my first approach; remove the function and doing the inline table and I got the same performance and the same execution plan than calling the function in a sub query, (which is good), in this particular case I preferred to maintain the function because is offering encapsulation and is been used in many other places, and I do not gain any extra performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would go for:

```
SELECT PayGroup, SystemType, MAX(EffDt) AS MaxEffDt
FROM ServiceAreas CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT StartPeriod() as sp) sp
WHERE EffDt > sp.sp
GROUP BY Paygroup, SystemType ;
```

Clearly the performance difference is the number of times the function is called.  You have more control if you put the function call in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Definetely not, I tested and I got a very similar execution plan than the worst case, and about the same time 50s..

Comment: @IsraelGarcia . . . That is really strange.  Could there be a performance hiccup in the function itself, where sometimes it takes a long time and sometimes it doesn't?

Comment: Gordon the function is a very simple call to a table that contain 1 record, the problem is because the Execution plan when I put a subquery is totally different than by invoking the function directly. Check the execution plans I added in the text of the question.